# Misunderstood notation in Applied Linear Algebra book.

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

Exercise *2.3* on page **42** of [this](http://vmls-book.stanford.edu) book by Boyd & Vandenberghe gives the following hint.

> *Hint*: $$s'(t) = s'(0) + \int_0^tF(\tau) \,\mathrm d \tau$$

In this context what is $\tau$?

Comment: I've changed the tags, because this ultimately is not really about linear algebra, even though you found it in a textbook on linear algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that context, $\tau$ is just a dummy variable. The author might as well have written that$$s'(t)=s'(0)+\int_0^tF(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$